# Invoke-Command not returning output from remote computer

Tags: powershell

I have below powershell command. Where it iterates through list of servers and get all the processes that are running. But, its not returning any output.

I have tried -Verbose switch but that did not worked

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}
```

Expected: It should output all the processes from remote machine.
Actual: Its not returning any data.

Comment: The code looks OK - is there any more code or details you've omitted?  Any errors or output at all?  What happens if you use `Enter-PsSession` instead?  Can you connect and run `Get-Process`?

Comment: I also wonder if `$ErrorActionPreference` has been set to SilentlyContinue and that is suppressing an error. Can you add the `-ErrorAction Continue` parameter to this command?

Comment: I am having a wpf form and calling this function (inside which this code resides) at a button click. If I change code to:

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
       $a = Get-Process
       Write-Host $a
}

I get below output:
-------------------
System.Diagnostics.Process (CcmExec) System.Diagnostics.Process (cmd) System.Diagnostics.Process (CmRcService) System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost) System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost) and so on....